# Add noindex and canonical with htaccess if an URL has a query string

Tags: .htaccess, seo, meta-tags, canonical-link, noindex

I have URLs with and without query strings, like:

```
  http://example.com/product
```

and

```
  http://example.com/product?color
```

I want that if any of my URLs has a query string (?anything), it gets with help of htaccess

```
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow"
```

and

```
  Header add Link 'My URL without query string; rel="canonical"'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: sure. parts a working, but i can't get an universal solution